# I want to captalize strings using lambda function (from a df where columns dtypes are object and int)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, analytics

my code:

```
if df.dtypes=='object':
    df.applymap(lambda x: x.upper())
```

Error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `df.dtypes` is not a scalar if your `DataFrame` has more than one columns. So it fails the condition test `if df.dtypes=='object'`.

Try the following code:

```
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].dtype=='object':
        df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

Comment: should be `dtype` not `dtypes` in second line of your code.

Comment: Although `.dtype` is more precise, they evaluate to the same value at a column. @Ank

Comment: Thank you so much, I have one question why cant we use .applymap() here

Comment: `applymap` apply a function element-wise to a `DataFrame`.  Here we are applying to a column `Series` , no `applymap` is available. But other than `apply` , `.map` is also a choice  and is dedicated for element-wise operation.  @sanjeev narain.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to convert the dataframe altogether. Use this code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype=='object':
        df[col] = df[col].str.upper())
```

Hope that works! Because I have personally checked this right now..